# Regular expression to extract n-values from a string

Tags: regex

Can regex extract the values embedded within a string, as identified by a variable template defined earlier within the same string?  Or is this better handled in Java?

For example: "2012 Ferrari [F12] - Ostrich Leather interior [F12#OL] - Candy Red Metallic [F12#3]"  The variable template is the first string encountered with square brackets, e.g. [F12], and the desired variables are found within subsequent instances of that template, e.g. 'OL' and '3'.

Comment: Are you using Java's implementation of regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are mentioning Java, I'll assume you are using the Java implementation, [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Java's Pattern supports so called *back references*, which can be used to match the same value a previous *capturing group* matched.

Unfortunately you cannot extract multiple values from a single capturing group, so you'll have to hardcode the number of templates you want to match, if you want to do this with a single pattern.

For one variable, it could look like this:

```
\[(.*?)\].*?\[\1#(.*?)\]
  ^^^^^          ^^^^^ variable
 template     ^^ back reference to whatever template matched
```

You can add more optional matches by wrapping them in optional non-capturing groups like this:

```
\[(.*?)\].*?\[\1#(.*?)\](?:.*?\[\1#(.*?)\])?(?:.*?\[\1#(.*?)\])?
                        ^ optional group    ^ another one
```

This would match up to three variables:

```
    String s = "2012 Ferrari [F12] - Ostrich Leather interior [F12#OL] - Candy Red Metallic [F12#3]";
    String pattern = "\\[(.*?)\\].*?\\[\\1#(.*?)\\](?:.*?\\[\\1#(.*?)\\])?(?:.*?\\[\\1#(.*?)\\])?";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }

    // prints F12, OL, 3, null
```

If you'll need to match any number of variables, however, you'll have to resort to extracting the template in a first pass and then embedding it in a second pattern:

```
    // compile once and store in a static variable
    Pattern templatePattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");

    String s = "2012 Ferrari [F12] - Ostrich Leather interior [F12#OL] - Candy Red Metallic [F12#3]";

    Matcher templateMatcher = templatePattern.matcher(s);

    if (!templateMatcher.find()) {
        return;
    }

    String template = templateMatcher.group(1);
    Pattern variablePattern = Pattern.compile("\\[" + Pattern.quote(template) + "#(.*?)\\]");

    Matcher variableMatcher = variablePattern.matcher(s);
    while (variableMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(variableMatcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: I need the two-pass method. Works great. Thanks for both!